# como almacenar una valor de un form en una variable permanente en javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, registro, cuenta-usuario

Ahora estoy intentando hacer un registro, quiero almacenar el nombre de usuario y la contraseña en dos variables creando las variables dinamicamente (por ejemplo si el usuario_7 ya existe que se cree el usuario_8) y que estas variables no se sobreescriban al volver a introducir el nombre y la contraseña si no que se creen nuevas variables con un numero mayor por ejemplo si el usuario_16 ya existe que se cree el usuario_17
no se si me estoy explicando bien
espero que puedan ayudarme

Comment: lo que enrealidad almacenas es el valor de la variable ejemplo ```let user = "usuario_1";``` y esta puede cambiar su valor a ```"usuario_2"``` o ```"usuario_3"```  si quieres guardar todas estas variables hazlo en un array

Comment: @christian mi idea era que cuando el usuario1 se registrara su nombre se almacenara en una variable (usuario1 = "juan") y su contraseña(contraseña1 = "yosoyjuan123") pero cuando se registre el usuario2 se almacenara en usuario2 y contraseña2, creo que si se podria usar un array pero aun no estoy seguro de como

Answer (score 2):

¿Hola cómo estás?... La verdad no entiendo porqué manejarías un sistema de usuarios con variables dinámicas, pero intenté recrear esto igualmente para ayudarte.

Hacerlo con variables dinamicas me parece un tanto dificil o imposible, por lo que lo hice con propiedades dinámicas de la siguiente manera:

```js
//tus usuarios almacenados
let myUsers = {
  user_1: {
    name: 'juan',
    age: 34,
  },
  user_2: {
    name: 'maria',
    age: 44,
  },
  user_3: {
    name: 'jesus',
    age: 25,
  },
};

//creamos un nuevo usuario
const myNewUser = {
  name: 'jose',
  age: 56,
};

//averiguamos el último usuario actual
const usersLength = Object.keys(myUsers).length;

//agregamos el nuevo usuario
myUsers[`user_${usersLength + 1}`] = myNewUser;

//imprimo los nuevos usuarios
console.log(myUsers);
```

Pienso que el código habla por si solo, lo único que te dejaría como referencia es el [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) que utilizé para convertir las propiedades del objeto en un arreglo.

### Edit:

Pues valla, me dijeron que no tuve en cuenta la contraseña, pero siendo sincero vuelvo y digo, me parece un poco raro manejar los usuarios aquí con js, lo correcto sería hacerlo desde un backend ya sea con [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro-whatis.php) o [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/es/), en el caso de nodeJS, podrían hashear la contraseña con algún módulo como [Bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) o algunos de los que existen...

Comment: buen ejemplo, aunque podrias haber manejado a los usuarios como objetos, ademas algo que nadie dice es que la contraseña no debe ser guardada en texto plano sino como un *hash* , en caso de tu ejemplo no existe contraseña (como dije es un ejemplo asi que no hay problema)

Comment: @christian pues ya edité la respuesta con lo que pienso de eso, como bien dije, se me hace raro hacerlo desde el cliente, aparte de que es demasiado pero demasiado inseguro, pero igual gracias, lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima!

Comment: Hola @JesúsGarcía No se nada de php y por eso queria hacerlo con js, pero no pense que seria tan dificil hacerlo del lado del cliente (e inseguro), gracias por intentar ayudar, claro que votare (si supiera como xd), intentare aprender php gracias!

Comment: @minombre, el voto es en la flecha hacia arriba jjsjas, y en cuanto a lo de como crear un flujo de usuarios, pues te recomiendo con nodeJs, o por lo menos es con lo que siempre trabajo, la verdad q nodeJS ya está reemplazando a PHP.

Comment: @JesúsGarcía se entiende lo que dices, por eso hay que dar detalles y hacerle saber a la persona que lo que hace no es correcto

Comment: @BetaM, lo siento, no volverá a pasar, que pena

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar localStorage como fuente de almacenamiento de datos,  estos datos los guardas en formato JSON, únicamente tendrías que hacer un parse de los datos que guardes, esto te simplifica bastante la vida ya que al final lo que guardas es un array y solo deberías buscar dentro del mismo.

Guardar data
`localStorage.setItem(“users”, JSON.stringify([[“user”=>”paca la vaca”,”password”=>”passDeVaca”]])`

Recuperar data
`let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(“users”)`

Comment: Eso si que no lo sabia ¿como creo el json?

Comment: @minombre no se crea el *json* solo se crea un *array* que luego se convierte a *json* con le metodo **JSON.stringify()**

Answer (score 0):

Existen muchas formas de hacerlo pero esto, si bien no es la mejor, me parece más gráfica para que entiendas la idea. Para generar nombres de variables dinámicas en un objeto, solo debes utilizar corchetes "[]" para declarar la llave.

```javascript
const usuarios = [];
const registroUsuario = (usuario, pass) => {
    const index = usuarios.length + 1;
    const nuevoUsuario = {}
    nuevoUsuario[`usuario_${index}`] = usuario;
    nuevoUsuario[`contraseña_${index}`] = pass;
    usuarios.push(nuevoUsuario);
}

registroUsuario('Juan', 'Juan123');
registroUsuario('Juan', 'Juan123');
registroUsuario('Juan', 'Juan123');

// si imprimes la variable usuarios
[
    {usuario_1: "Juan", contraseña_1: "Juan123"},
    {usuario_2: "Juan", contraseña_2: "Juan123"},
    {usuario_3: "Juan", contraseña_3: "Juan123"}
]
```

Si corres lo que escribí, verás que se crean 3 Juan cada uno dentro de un objeto en el arreglo.